# know a good .net library for linear algebra?

Tags: .net, math, .net-4.0, linear-algebra

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# linear algebra library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392857/c-linear-algebra-library)

Can you recommend a good .net library for linear algebra?  I've seen libraries ranging from free to $999.  I'm not opposed to paying, but would like to keep costs down.  If you've used such a library, could you comment on your experience developing against the lib?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960714/good-linear-algebra-package

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392857/c-linear-algebra-library

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610641/what-are-your-experiences-with-numerics-libraries-for-c-and-which-would-you-rec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET specific libraries:

[Math.NET Numerics](http://mathnetnumerics.codeplex.com/)
[ILNumerics.NET](http://ilnumerics.net/)
[Meta Numerics](http://metanumerics.codeplex.com/)
[NMath](http://www.centerspace.net/products/nmath/)